# Application crashes when using Adobe PDF Reader

Tags: vb.net

I have a line of code that draws in the value from another form when the user control is loaded

```
usernameconstant.Text = Mainpage.usernameconstantmain.Text
```

This works fine under normal circumstances but I need a PDF reader on the same page, when I add an Adobe PDF Reader the application completely stops working and giving me this error in relation to the code above.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The form referred to itself during construction from a default instance, which led to infinite recursion.  Within the Form's constructor refer to the form using 'Me.''
```

I tried deleting the first line of code that draws in the value from another page to see if it was really causing the problem and the error did not pop up anymore but I still need the value from the separate form with a PDF reader and i'm not sure why this error keeps popping up.

```
Public Class Submissioncontrol

Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
Dim Myconnection As String = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=password;database=project"
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim result As Integer
Dim imgpath As String
Dim arrImage() As Byte
Dim sql As String

Dim connection As MySqlConnection
Dim ride As MySqlCommand


Public Property studentid
Public Property title
Public Property deadline



Private Sub Submissioncontrol_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    usernameconstant.Text = Mainpage.usernameconstantmain.Text

    todaysdate.Text = Today

    Dim number As New Random
    idbox.Text = number.Next(1, 1000000)


End Sub

Private Sub Submit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    connection = New MySqlConnection

    connection.ConnectionString =
    "server=localhost;userid=root;password=aaronwong;database=finalyearproject"
    ' Establishes connection to mysqldatabase '

    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

    Try
        connection.Open()
        Dim aaasaccess As String
        aaasaccess = "insert into finalyearproject.studentsubmissions (submissionid, studentnumber, time, date, deadline, title, work, modulename) values ('" & idbox.Text & "','" & usernameconstant.Text & "','" & todaystime.Text & "','" & todaysdate.Text & "','" & deadlinesubmission.Text & "','" & titlesubmission.Text & "','" & workload.Text & "','" & modulename.Text & "')"
        ' inserts into specific database schema with the named columns '
        ride = New MySqlCommand(aaasaccess, connection)
        reader = ride.ExecuteReader

        MessageBox.Show("Created")
        connection.Close()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        connection.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    todaystime.Text = TimeOfDay


End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click_2(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click


    Try
        conn.ConnectionString = Myconnection
        conn.Open()

        sql = "insert into studentsubmissions(submissionid, studentnumber, time, date, deadline, title, work, modulename) VALUES (@subid, @stunumber, @subtime, @subdate, @workdeadline, @stutitle, @stuwork, @workmodulename)"
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandText = sql




        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subid", idbox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stunumber", usernameconstant.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subtime", todaystime.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subdate", todaysdate.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@workdeadline", deadlinesubmission.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stutitle", titlesubmission.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stuwork", workload.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@workmodulename", modulename.Text)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MessageBox.Show("Created")
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try


End Sub


End Class



>   Final Year Project.exe!Final_Year_Project.Submissioncontrol.Submissioncontrol_Load(Object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 30   Basic   Symbols loaded.
[External Code]     Annotated Frame
Final Year Project.exe!Final_Year_Project.Submissioncontrol.New() Line 13   Basic   Symbols loaded.
[External Code]     Annotated Frame
Final Year Project.exe!Final_Year_Project.Submissioncontrol.Submissioncontrol_Load(Object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 30   Basic   Symbols loaded.
[External Code]     Annotated Frame
Final Year Project.exe!Final_Year_Project.Submissioncontrol.New() Line 13   Basic   Symbols loaded.
[External Code]     Annotated Frame
Final Year Project.exe!Final_Year_Project.Login.Button1_Click(Object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 33    Basic   Symbols loaded.
[External Code]     Annotated Frame
```

Comment: Where EXACTLY is that line of code located?

Comment: @jmcilhinney In the 'Load' 

           Private Sub Submissioncontrol_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

Comment: Of which form class? If it's not `Mainpage`, is your PDF viewer control on the `Mainpage` or the same form as `usernameconstant`? Also, can you edit your question and post the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Sorry, I forgot to mention, the first line of code and the PDF viewer are on a User Control and both in the same User Control.

Comment: And is that user control on the `Mainpage` form?

Comment: It's just very bad practice for a user control to be pulling data from a form via the default instance like that.  This is an example of why many experienced developers - myself included - think that default instances are a bad idea.  They make it easier for beginners to do certain things and one of those things is do something really, really bad like this. The proper way to do this is for you to add a property to your user control that, when set, will pass the value on to the child control.  You then set that property from the form. Data is pushed in by the form, not pulled in by the UC.